# What would prevent a vacuum pump from drawing full vacuum?

Tags: vacuum-pump

I recently bought a vacuum pump secondhand (Pittsburgh 3cfm two stage pump). My manifold gauges only show it drawing around 23 inches hg of vacuum though. It should be capable of much more. The outside of the pump was covered in some sawdust when I got it, but the oil inside the pump is at the correct level and it looks perfectly clear.

Is there anything else I should be checking in order to get it working properly? How can I tell if it needs to be replaced instead?

Comment: With most pumps, it is the seals inside that are the most important.  The outside does not matter.

Comment: How long have you let it run? There could be a lot of condensed water to be boiled off from the oil if it's sat for a while. Or, running long enough might get to the point where the stuck vane (if that's it) comes loose and starts working again. Let it run at least until it's good and warm. A stuck vane is a reasonable guess. A leak in the piping/hose connections is the other main cause of poor vacuum.

Comment: Yah, I let it run for quite a while. I think it was around an hour. It pretty quickly got to 23 in hg, then just stopped making progress. I also tried disconnecting/reconnecting everything to make sure I hadn't messed up any of the connections somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a rotary vane pump. If your oil is recently changed (not just clear), your hoses and seals are in good condition, your gauge is accurate, and it's still not pulling a hard vacuum, one of the vanes is probably damaged. If you haven't changed the oil, and changing it improves things, you might need to change the oil a few times and run it for a while to get it working well. Unfortunately parts are usually tough to get for Harbor Freight tools, which means it may be beyond repair.

Comment: One of the things buying higher quality tools gets you, beyond better design and manufacturing, is better repairability.

Comment: There are oil tests where you send a sample of used oil in to get a reading of how bad/good the oil is protecting the metal parts/bad wear.  Usually for automotive engines, but helpful for other oil protected devices.  No good if the oil was just changed to look good.

Comment: A vacuum pump uses so little oil that it's probably just worth changing it a few times and letting it run to see if things clear up before you decide if it needs to be tossed.

Comment: Sounds great. I haven't changed the oil yet. I'll try doing that a few times and see if it improves.